# ORA-01031 when creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I started reading a Tom Kyte's book and immediately ran into a problem :) - sql is executed just fine but CREATE VIEW based on that sql returns ORA-01031.

Commands below were executed on behalf of "system" user:

```
create or replace view stats
as select 'STAT...' || a.name name, b.value
      from v$statname a, v$mystat b
     where a.statistic# = b.statistic#
    union all
    select 'LATCH.' || name,  gets
      from v$latch
    union all
    select 'STAT...Elapsed Time', hsecs from v$timer;
```

> ERROR at line 3: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

However executing the sql renders no errors:

```
select 'STAT...' || a.name name, b.value
      from v$statname a, v$mystat b
     where a.statistic# = b.statistic#
    union all
    select 'LATCH.' || name,  gets
      from v$latch
    union all
    select 'STAT...Elapsed Time', hsecs from v$timer;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: do **not** create new objects as the `SYSTEM` user

Comment: You may not have rights to create a view.

Comment: system was used to figure out lack of privilege - just for the sake of simplicity

Comment: @OldProgrammer system user does have "create view" privilege - verified that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system` user lacks `select any dictionary` privilege, or  `select on [v_$mystat|v_$statname | v_$latch]` object privilege granted directly(not through the `dba` role), not the `create view` one. That's the main reason why you cannot create that view in the system schema. As soon as you grant one of the mentioned above privileges to the `system` user, you will be able to create your view successfully, but, try to **never** create user objects in system schemas, whether it's `sys` or `system`. Create separate user, grant appropriate privileges and do whatever you want to do.

```
SQL> show user;
USER is "SYSTEM"

SQL> create or replace view v_1 as
  2    select *
  3      from v$mystat;

from v$mystat
         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges 


SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> grant select any dictionary to system;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn system/pwd -- connect as system

Connected.

SQL> create or replace view v_1 as
  2    select *
  3      from v$mystat;

View created.

SQL> drop view v_1;

View dropped.
```

Comment: One thing is still not clear to me - why "select any dictionary" is not required for selects but necessary for "create view as..."?

Comment: @ValeryC In fact, `system` user has `select any dictionary` system privilege granted, but it is granted through the `dba` role, not directly. To be able to create a view that references an object in another schema or be able to reference that object in PL/SQL some privileges have to be granted directly, not through the role.